# Invalid Launch Image - itunesconnect

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

**Hi All,
I have tried uploading the app in appstore and through apploader it was successfully. In the itunes connect the status changed to "Upload Received". But after some time the status got changed to "Invalid Binary". 
Below is the mail received :
"Invalid Launch Image - Your app contains a launch image with a size modifier that is only supported for apps built with the iOS 6.0 SDK or later."
I have built the app using Xcode Version 4.3.3 (4E3002). Please help.**

Comment: .. you have to accept one of the answers of your question.... occasionally..

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would get 4.5.2. 4.3.3 is a little old and certain patches may not be available.

https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Comment: yeah but if I build the app using 4.5.5, i have these issues :
1. I have used Shrekit and it used Apple LVM 3.0, so this has to be used in Xcode 4.3.3
2.After building the app using Xcode 4.5.5 , it automatically enables TILT mode. But my code does not have TILT option enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you build your Xcode 4.3.3 required code as a library or framework in 4.3.3, then add it as a library in 4.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

I think.. your iOS target is 4.2 or below..

You have a choice: target above iOS 4.3 and fully support the iPhone 5.... or support older iOS versions but have a letterboxed app on iPhone 5 - in that case you must delete the Default-568h@2x.png file

EDIT

"If you build your project with an older version of Xcode (3.2, 4.2) you'll get an error* when the file Default-568h@2x.png is present as you HAVE TO upgrade Xcode to the latest version in order to build against the latest SDK (6.x). The latest iOS target version supported when building with iOS SDK 6 is 4.3. " ..check [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/153862-Good-to-know-iOS-4-5-6-and-invalid-binary)